# PHP : How to pass get value in url

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pass both stock (user input) and id in one url   one I try this I get *Undefined index: stock* 
 is the way I'm passing the input value wrong ?

```
<?php



session_start();
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customers WHERE customers_id='1'";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_products";

$get = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($get);

$customerName = $row['customer_email'];
echo "Welcome $customerName";



$data= mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    $pid = $row['pid'];
    echo "<form action='' method='GET'>

 <input type=text name=stock value=1><br>
<a href='stock.php?id=" . $pid . "?stock=" . $_GET['stock'] . "'> Add</a>

                      </form>";




}

?>
```

thank you everyone for your help this is what I did to fix the error my get value is always empty If I don't press enter

```
echo "<form action='' method='GET'>

                     <input type=text name=stock value=1><br>

                             </form>";
    $_GET['stock'] = 1;
    if (isset($_GET["stock"])) {
        $x = $_GET['stock'];
        echo "<a href='stock.php?id=" . $pid . "&stock=" . $_GET['stock'] . "'> Add</a>";
    }
```

Comment: Use `&` for second parameter as `stock.php?id=" . $pid . "&stock=`

Comment: @Saty I've added the '&' but I still get 'Undefined index: stock' in this page and when I l click the link it show 'stock=' and there is no value

Comment: `print_r($_GET);` and post its value

Comment: @Saty I fixed it thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Just change ? with & before stock.

```
  echo "<form action='' method='GET'><input type=text name=stock value=1><br>
<a href='stock.php?id=" . $pid . "&stock=" . $_GET['stock'] . "'> Add</a> </form>";
```

Comment: I've added the `&` but I still get `Undefined index: stock` in this page and when I l click the link it show 'stock=' and there is no value

Comment: first check $pid and $_GET['stock'] contains the value

Comment: thank you for your help I realized that get will always be empty so I set it to 1 and echo the link outside the form

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/php/event-detail.php?event_id=$event_id">
```

this how you use to pass values to another page. you can refer this http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=48611